# Get the entry back after INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Once I add data via PDO, I would like to get the new entry back. I cannot use `alias` in my `SELECT` query as it is not unique, and I can't use `id` as it is an autoincrement index. Is there a PDO way to get the entry back once you run `execute()` over an `INSERT` query?

```
$db_target = new PDO (...);
$stmt = $db_target->prepare("INSERT INTO table (`alias`) VALUES (".$randomString.")");
$stmt->execute();
// how to query for the entry I've just added?
```

Structure of `table`:

```
id (autoincrement) | alias (NOT unique)
```

Comment: Can you maybe make `alias` into a variable, and query for the last entry on that table using that variable?

Comment: @tola that would be the wrongest  thing to do

Comment: Warning, you are using a [cargo cult prepared statement](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/cargo_cult_prepared_statement) that protects nothing!

Comment: @YourCommonSense I know that, this is just a simplified example, I use `prepare` and `bindValue` in the real code. I love your username btw.

Answer (score 2):

After you insert you can use `lastInsertId()`

```
db_target = new PDO (...);
$stmt = $db_target->prepare("INSERT INTO table (`alias`) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->execute([$randomString]);
$id = $db_target->lastInsertId();
```

The value is `$id` will be the auto incrementing primary key.